# Application of superposition theorem

Tags: circuit-analysis, superposition

I find superposition to be a noob's approach towards the analysis of circuits containing multiple sources... An experienced person will probably not use it... How do we deal with various sources at a single time? Is there any trick which makes the analysis easier? How should we approach?

Comment: Why do you consider it a "noob's" approach?

Comment: You don't always bring a chainsaw when all you actually need is a scissors. Your example is more of the scissors variety. Are you asking about how to apply the chainsaw to this one?

Comment: As a practicing engineer, I would hardly consider superposition "a noob's approach." That said, I almost always find nodal analysis the easiest to perform for typical textbook problems (like this one).

Comment: We take 1 source at a time.. Makes the problem long. @awjlogan

Comment: Okay. You want the chainsaw then. Use nodal analysis. Ground the bottom node (you get to do that once in a circuit) and call it 0 V. The (+) node of the voltage source is... uh... +18 V. The only remaining node is the top node. For this, the equation is \$\frac{V_X}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{V_X}{4\:\Omega}=6\:\textrm{A} + \frac{0\:\textrm{V}}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{+18\:\textrm{V}}{4 \: \Omega}\$. Solve for \$V_X\$. Done. The rest is trivial detail.

Comment: You open the 6V source and solve the circuit, then you short the voltage source and solve the circuit. If you want an answer then please provide an attempt at a solution

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its Homework without an attempt at a solution

Comment: i never asked anyone to solve me that problem..that is an elementary level problem..my question was different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with superposition. But I would go like this (**EDIT** - applies to the initially present but currently deleted example circuit):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9nIwT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Two simple equations with two unknowns:
$$ I_1 = I_2 + I_3 $$
$$ V = I_2 \cdot R_2 = V_1 + I_3 \cdot R_1$$

Substituting the first one into the second one will give 
$$(I_1-I_3)R_2 = V_1 + I_3\cdot R_1$$

The only unknown here is \$I_3\$ and I will let the reader to solve the rest.

That said, it is *not* a very systematic approach, but it is easier sometimes for simple circuits like this one. For more complex circuits the superposition and other *formal* methods are better suited.